# MVC 5 : NameForModel render twice the name and id of a field

Tags: asp.net-mvc, data-annotations, mvc-editor-templates

I try to modify an editor template to use the data annotations. And I get some weird thing. Here below the editorTemplate.

```
@model Translations<string>

@{

    Translation<string> t = null;
    if (Model != null && Model.Values != null)
    {
        t = Model.Values.FirstOrDefault(p => p.Language == KalowContext.Instance.CurrentLanguage);
    }
    t = t ?? new Translation<string>();

    var validationAttributes = Html.GetUnobtrusiveValidationAttributes("");
}

@Html.TextBox(Html.NameForModel().ToString(), t.Value, new RouteValueDictionary(validationAttributes)
    {
        { "class", "form-control" }
    }
    )


<input class="form-control" type="text" name="@(Html.NameFor(m => Model))" value="@t.Value">
```

and this is the output, as you can the @Html.TextBox is rendering the name and the id attributes twice. Which works fine in the second input.

```
    <input name="dc.Name.dc.Name" class="form-control" id="dc_Name_dc_Name" type="text" value="Afghanistan" data-val-required="The Name field is required." data-val="true">
    <input name="dc.Name" class="form-control" type="text" value="Afghanistan">
```

Any suggestions ? Thank you !

Here is the class Translations and Translation

```
public class Translations<T>
{
    public List<Translation<T>> Values { get; set; }

    public Translations()
    {

    }
}


public class Translation<T>
{
    public ObjectId Language { get; set; }

    public T Value { get; set; }

    public Translation()
    {

    }

    public Translation(ObjectId language, T value)
    {
        Language = language;
        Value = value;
    }

}
```

Comment: What is your model in the template? And what is the purpose of the `EditorTemplate` (what are you trying to do that cannot be done more simply using the built in templates?)

Comment: The model is an array of a structure used for translations. Something like Translations<T> that contains an array of Translation<T> with Language and Value. to make it easy I just want to use EditorFor(t=>t.Name) ... and adapt the templateeditor, that will get the right value for a fixed language => that why we have something like t.Value :=)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<input class="form-control" type="text" name="@(Html.NameFor(m => Model))"
   @Html.Raw(string.Join(" ", 
       validationAttributes.
          Select(x => x.Key.ToString() + "=\"" + x.Value + "\"")))
              value="@t.Value">
```

Intermediate solution... but as there is no audience. I keep it that way. :=)

Comment: Ever found anything better?